# php array sorting by Multiple Dates

Tags: arrays

Could an array be sorted by multiple dates, see example source below

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Test
        [StartDate] => 2018-09-01 00:00:00
        [EndDate] => 2018-09-07 00:00:00
        [Days] => 7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Another Test
        [StartDate] => 2018-11-05 00:00:00
        [EndDate] => 2018-11-12 00:00:00
        [Days] => 8
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Something Else
        [StartDate] => 2018-09-08 00:00:00
        [EndDate] => 2018-10-01 00:00:00
        [Days] => 24
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Other
        [StartDate] => 2018-11-13 00:00:00
        [EndDate] => 2018-11-13 00:00:00
        [Days] => 1
    )
)
```

I've been trying to figure out how to re-arrange the array so that the array will be sorted by the start date, which I've managed to figure out perfectly.

What I'm struggling the most with is looping through the array again and re-arranging the array once more, so that the next event start date is > previous event end date, So what I would like to achieve is the order of 'Test', 'Something Else', 'Another Test', 'Other'

I've recently gotten to grips with arrays and learning quite quickly however I'm still a beginner, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a [custom comparator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). Something like:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a.endDate== $b.startDate) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a.endDate < $b.startDate) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($a, "cmp");
```

**EDIT**

To further explain what is happening. When you call a sorting function, whatever the underlying algorithm is it compares the elements to decide which one comes first. This order is trivially defined on primitive types (e.g. 1 is obviously less then 2), but on objects you may need to define how you want them to be ordered.

In your case, you want that when you compare two objects, you want to apply some criteria based on the ending and starting date. That is what you do with a custom comparator.

A comparator receives two elements to compare. It compares them, and if they are equal it returns 0. If the first one must be placed before the second one, it returns -1. If the first one must be placed after the second one, it returns +1. No other return values accepted.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try even though I don't fully understand it:)

Comment: Edited the answer and added further details.

Comment: Thank you for the extended explanation, It helped me understand it better, I'll integrate it into my array for loop shortly.

Comment: If you feel it is appropriate, please consider selecting the answer. Cheers

Comment: Hi Tu.ma, Finally managed to get the page to display normally with reading the multidimensional array, I do have a question, the above array snippet came out of a multidimensional array, I have tried the usort function and it doesn't appear to do anything and I have done quite a lot research into it, but I don't really understand it. Does the usort function loop through the entire array or would I have to loop through the array in the function? Thank you.

Comment: The usort function takes care of looping and everything related to sorting. You just have to call it. I am not sure why it's not working for you, you should post a reproducer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I'll write up a snippet and start with minimal amount of data and try again, maybe I'm not passing the array correctly, silly question, how do I post a reproducer as I'm still quite new with posting? I'll post the snippet as soon as I can. I do believe the function will work for me, it's just a matter of utilizing it and that's where I think I'm struggling.

Comment: Hi Tu.ma, Managed to get the code to work, I created a loop to go through the multidimensional array and then sorted each sub array using the usort method, I didn't want to sort the main arrays, only the sub arrays and that's where I was getting stuck (re-coded the basics in a blank window to make sure everything worked), I just have 1 last question, how do I get the dates in chronological order? Thank you once again.

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k0yy-1qmb I created a fiddle to show you what I mean

Comment: Oh, I looked different from the question snippet. Glad you managed to make it work.

Comment: I thought the function would just run without telling it to run for each sub category however the function didn't and only figured it out when I created the new snippet.